# MS Access 2010 VBA Combobox

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

i am new to programming field for MS Access and VBScript.

I have a question that need help from here.

first of all i have 2 tables in my MS Access database.
1 is Web, 1 is Owner.
Relationship is 1 to many (1 web can have multiple owners)

I have a form which consists of 3 comboboxes.
combobox1 is use for webURL
combobox2 is use for ownername1
combobox3 is use for ownername2

So, how can I make combobox2 and combobox3 to display the ownername1 and ownername2 respectively when I select different webURL (in combobox1).
Furthermore, this combobox2 and combobox3 drop down list must include all the ownername in table Owner (So that i can change the ownername to other person of that particular web when i click the button update)

Now i only able to populate webURL data into combobox1.
The rest i have no idea how to do..

Here is the sample data:

**Web Table**

follow the format

webID (PK), webURL

1          Stackoverflow.com

2          Google.com

3          Yahoo,com

**Owner Table**

follow the format

ownerID (PK), ownerName, webID (FK)

1 Law 1

2 Hans 1

3 Kent 2

4 Howard 3

5 William 3

Your help is very much appreciate in here.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you determine which owner is ownername1 and which is ownername2?  This might be clear if you show us a brief set of sample data.

Comment: @HansUp i am sorry that i am not able to post images on my post as i dun have enough reputation. I edited my post with some brief data, i hope u understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a the `combobox.rowsource =` feature.  Here's a quick example...

```
Private Sub Test_Combo1_Click()
'when a value is selected or clicked from combobox1 then'

Dim var As String

'take the ID'
var = Me.Test_Combo1.Column(0)
Debug.Print var

'and use SQL statement to grab the corresponding link'
Me.Test_Combo2.RowSource = "Select ID, Link from URL where ID = " & var

End Sub
```

Comment: this is working, but the Test_Combo2 drop down list only shows the ID for which have relationship with var.
What i want is, Test_Combo2 shows the ID related with var in the box itself, and then when i click the drop down list, it will show the entire list of ID.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
Private Sub Test_Combo1_Click()
'when a value is selected or clicked from combobox1 then'

Dim var As String

'take the ID'
var = Me.Test_Combo1.Column(0)
Debug.Print var

'and use SQL statement to grab the corresponding link'
Me.Test_Combo2.RowSource = "Select ID, Link from URL 
Me.Text_Combo2.Value = var
End Sub
```